# HTTP Push "1 new answer"

Tags: bug, live-refresh

(Or is it "Show 1 new answer")

I think it's a bit faulty - if a user answers a question, and then deletes the answer, the "1 new answer" notification is still there. Clicking it just removes the notification and shows "1 Answer" with no answer underneath it.

Comment: To fix the problem, you'll have to check to see if other users posted an answer while the other one is deleted, do some math and a few calisthenics, and check for collisions.  Not worth the effort.

Answer (score 1):

This is by design. The reason being that the answer actually is there, however you do not have the reputation to see it.

10k+ reputation users can see deleted answers. Of which, there is one on your question ([Microsoft AJAX vs jQuery AJAX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17617980/microsoft-ajax-vs-jquery-ajax)).

It states:

> One good [article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/139787/What-s-the-Difference-between-WCF-and-Web-Services) about the differences between WCF and Web-Services. This might be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

The problem occurs very, very infrequently, and while it may be odd or disconcerting to someone when it happens, it's not worth the additional network load.

In fact it might even be more annoying to have the "1 new answer" show, then suddenly disappear without explanation.  If this was fixed we'd eventually get the bug report, "1 new answer should updated to 1 new answer deleted, rather than disappear."

Given the infrequency and low severity of this issue, I don't think it should be altered.

Comment: Worth to mention that the inbox new items alert behave this way already. Many times I see it showing "1" and before I have chance to click, it disappears into thin air as the comment was deleted.